# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 5 elements

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file using Pandas. But while using the pd.read_csv I get a ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 5 elements.

Here's the code:

```
# load train data
data = pd.read_csv('training1.6.csv',error_bad_lines=False , encoding='iso-8859-1',low_memory=False)
data.columns = ['label','id','date','user','text']
data.head(2)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-21e4215846cd> in <module>()
      1 data = pd.read_csv('training1.6.csv',error_bad_lines=False , encoding='iso-8859-1')
----> 2 data.columns = ['label','id','date','user','text']
      3 data.head(2)

2 frames
pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    181             raise ValueError(
    182                 "Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old} elements, new "
--> 183                 "values have {new} elements".format(old=old_len, new=new_len)
    184             )
    185 

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

I tried the dtype and low_memory but to no avail. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you checked what `data.shape` gives you?

Comment: ----> 2 data.columns = ['label','id','date','user','text'],                         your error is in: `data.columns = ['label','id','date','user','text']` , try: `data.columns = ['label','id','date','user','text', 'other1', 'itworks!']`

Comment: @ansev Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you clarify what was causing the problem. Why did adding two empty columns solve the error?

Comment: Because, as the error says, `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 5 elements`..

Comment: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 5 elements` 
you have a data frame with 7 columns, each column has a name, you are trying to change the name of the columns, so if you specify a list you must specify a list of 7 names and not 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You didn't get that error while using the `pd.read_csv()`, but in the next command.)

The `data` dataframe (which you constructed from the .csv file) has 7 columns, but in the command

```
 data.columns = ['label','id','date','user','text']
```

you provided only 5 column labels.

Add missing two, e. g.

```
data.columns = ['label', 'id', 'date', 'user', 'text', 'col_6', 'col_7']
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some unavailable values in the column which you want to split in the future. eg. the text have more kinds of value than before. you'd better go back to the dataframe to ch enc if some null or empty in you the column